# Tool to explore GUI controls of a running .NET application needed

Tags: .net, user-interface

Is there any tool to explore properties of GUI controls (such as "Text" or "Location") from a running .NET application?

Answer (score 1):

[Hawkeye](http://www.acorns.com.au/Projects/Hawkeye/) can do this. With it, you can inspect any .Net GUI and view the properties of its controls.

Additionally, Microsoft have a tool called [UISpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx) (that is part of the Windows SDK) that does a similar job. This is basically a .Net version of Spy++.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is [Snoop](http://www.blois.us/Snoop/) which includes a great exploded 3D view of the layout, great for seeing how things nest.

Comment: Snoop only works with WPF. It does not work with Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/) for this kind of thing.

It comes with a tool which allows you to inspect all the elements of a GUI. Seemed to work pretty well for me. AutoIt scripts can be pretty useful too, allowing you to access these GUI element values programmatically.